# Does a resource equal true in PHP?

Tags: php

According to PHP documenation for `mysql_query()`:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
> resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
> error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
> mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

If SELECT returns a resource on succes, does it actually return TRUE on succes? So is it still valid to do?:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * WHERE 1=1');
if ($result) {
    //resultset is valid?
}

?>
```

I'm almost sure it does, but how does that work? Does mysql_query() just returns several properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PHP manual entry on booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered
>   FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (**including any resource**).

The emphasis is mine, but applies to your situation.

Also, do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.